# Singly linked list push_front won't reassign head

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am having trouble getting my `push_front` to work correctly. It seems that `new_head->next = head` won't correctly link new_head and head. My node class is the usual node class where `next` is a node pointer. My `push_back` function works fine. I don't see why `head` won't link to `new_head`.

```
template <class T> class mylist {
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;
    typedef mynode<T>* iterator;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    mylist() { create(); }
    mylist(size_type n, const T& val = T()) { create(n, val); }
    ~mylist() { uncreate(); }
    iterator begin() { return head; }
    iterator end() { return head + size(); }
    size_type size();
    void push_back(const T&);
    void push_front(const T&);
    void pop_back();
    void pop_front();

private:
    std::allocator<mynode<T>> alloc;
    mynode<T>* head;
    mynode<T>* tail;
    void create() { head = tail = 0; }
    void create(size_type, const T&);
    void uncreate();
};
```

---

```
template <class T> void mylist<T>::push_front(const T& t)
{
    iterator new_head = alloc.allocate(1);
    new_head->data = t;
    new_head->next = head;
    head = new_head;
    if(tail == 0)
        tail = head;
}
```

---

```
template <class T> void mylist<T>::push_back(const T& t)
{
    tail->next = alloc.allocate(1);
    tail = tail->next;
    tail->data = t;
    tail->next = 0;
}
```

---

`MAIN`

```
#include "mylist.h"
int main()
{
    mylist<int> lst(5, 2);
    lst.push_back(22);
    mylist<int>::iterator temp = lst.begin();
    while(temp != lst.end()) {
        std::cout << **temp << " ";
        temp++;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "list size: " << lst.size() << std::endl;
    lst.push_front(80);
    lst.push_back(7);
    lst.push_back(3);
    mylist<int>::iterator inc = lst.begin();
    while(inc != lst.end()) {
        std::cout << **inc << " ";
        inc++;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "list size: " << lst.size() << std::endl;
}
```

`OUTPUT`

```
2 2 2 2 2 22 
list size: 6
80 7 3 
list size: 3
```

---

`EDIT`

```
template <class T> void mylist<T>::create(size_type n, const T& t)
{
    head = alloc.allocate(1);
    head->data = t;
    head->next = alloc.allocate(1);
    mynode<T>* next = head->next;
    int i = 0;
    while(i != n-2) {
        next->data = t;
        next->next = alloc.allocate(1);
        next = next->next;
        ++i;
    }
    tail = next;
    tail->data = t;
    tail->next = 0;
}
```

---

`class mynode`

```
template <class T> class mynode {
public:
    mynode() : next(0) {}
    mynode(T a, mynode* n = 0) : data(a), next(n) {}
    mynode* next;
    mynode* operator++() { return this->next; }
    mynode* operator+(size_t n) {
        size_t cnt = 0;
        mynode* count = this;
        while(cnt != n) {
            ++cnt;
            count = count->next;
        }
        return count;
    }
    T& operator*() { return this->data; }
    T data;
};
```

---

`Example using operator+`

```
#include "mylist.h"
int main()
{
    mylist<int> test(5,5);
    mylist<int>::iterator n = test.begin();
    while(n != test.end()) {
        std::cout << **n << " ";
        n = n + 1;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    mylist<int> test2(6,6);
    mylist<int>::iterator m = test2.begin();
    while(m != test2.end() - 1) {
        std::cout << **m << " ";
        m = m->next;
        if(m == test2.end()-1)
            std::cout << **m;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

`Output from example`

```
5 5 5 5 5 
6 6 6 6 6 6
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `push_front()` and not your `operator++`?  What happens if you change `lst.push_back(22)` to `lst.push_front(22)` before that first `while` loop?  If it does insert 22 at the beginning, then the problem is with your iterator's `operator++` mutating the `next` pointers in your list of nodes.

Comment: What would happen if you did a `push_back()` on an empty list?

Comment: @JoeZ. It goes into an infinite loop when I make that change.

Comment: @Dochevsky:  Without seeing your `create(size_t, const T&)`, it seems there might be a problem there, too.  Your `push_front` looks fine.  Your `push_back` doesn't handle an empty list two ways (one, it derefs `tail` without checking if it's NULL first, and two, it doesn't update `head`).  What does your iterator type look like?

Comment: @JoeZ. Posted `create(size_t, const T&)` in the edit. It's true I haven't yet edited `push_back` to account for the empty list.

Comment: Hmmm... `create` should be a lot of fun when you pass in `n == 1`.  If you fix `push_back`, it seems like you should rewrite `create` in terms of `push_back`.   In any case, I'm still skeptical of your `operator++` in `mynode`.  Can you share it?

Comment: @JoeZ. Sure. I just didn't want to post all at once because of the clutter. See edit.

Comment: @JoeZ. Thanks for pointing that out `(n == 1)`. I added this in front to correct it. `if(n == 1) { head = tail = 0; push_back(t); return;} if(n == 2) { head = tail = 0; push_back(t); push_back(t); return; }`

Comment: You have a pre-increment ++, but you're using post-increment ++ in your `main`.  That seems a little... suspicious.

Comment: Actually, hold on:  Your `operator++` operates on `mynode<T>`, not `mynode<T>*`.  Is that operator even ever getting called?  When I tried to reproduce your code locally, I see that ++ just increments the pointer, whether I use preincrement or postincrement.  That's when it hit me.  Your iterator type can't be a bare pointer, it needs to be wrapped in an object.  You can either modify `mynode<T>` to be the iterator type directly, or wrap `mynode<T>*` in yet another object and move the `operator++` etc. to that object.

Comment: @JoeZ. So I would build another class inside the `mylist` class?

Comment: I would wrap `mynode<T>*` in another class, and move `operator++` and friends into that class.

Comment: @JoeZ. This would require me to overload all kinds of operators correct? Since I do comparisons like `!=`.

Comment: @JoeZ. How does all this relate to push_front though? push_front doesn't use any of these.

Comment: @Dochevsky:  I'm not sure your original code was actually following `->next` pointers when doing `iter++`.  I don't see how your `operator++` was getting called.  It seems more likely these objects were getting allocated sequentially on the heap and you were lucking out.  Do you still have your original code, and can you add a print statement to verify whether it was getting called?

Comment: @JoeZ. When I used `operator+` instead of `operator++` though, it calls `operator+`. When I comment out `operator+` I get an error because `+` was not defined. Also, if I make `head` and `tail` public and just manually `->next` it correctly proceeds to the next.

Comment: @JoeZ. I've posted some examples at the bottom.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40919/discussion-between-dochevsky-and-joe-z)

Comment: @JoeZ. So you were right. The `operator+` wasn't doing what I thought it was.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is push_back that works incorrectly. Change it the following way

```
template <class T> void mylist<T>::push_back(const T& t)
{
    mynode<T>* new_tail = alloc.allocate(1);
    new_tail->data = t;
    new_tail->next = 0;
    if ( tail == 0 )
    {
        head = new_tail;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = new_tail;
    }
    tail = new_tail;
}
```

Comment: And what would that do if `tail == 0`?  (ie. `push_back` on an empty list?)  I agree `push_back` is broken, but you haven't fixed it completely.

Comment: You really want this to mirror `push_front`, with `new_tail = alloc...`, and then `if (tail) { tail->next = new_tail; tail = new_tail; } else { head = tail = new_tail; }`

Comment: Joe Z thanks, I even did not look that tail is not checked.:) I updated my code.

Comment: Alright I fixed `push_back`. Did something else from your code though.

Comment: Put this in front of the original code:

`if(head == 0) { head = alloc.allocate(1); head->data = t; tail = head; tail->next = 0; return; }`